# Question on $\sigma$-algebra of coin toss experiment

Tags: probability, combinatorics, measure-theory

> We toss a fair coin until we get two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails. Each sequence of $n$ coin tosses has a probability of $\frac{1}{2^n}$.
>
> What is the probability that $n\leq 5$?

Our sample solution simply states that:

"*Let be $A_1$ the event that $n\leq 5$ and $A_1^c$ its complement. Then, $A_1^c$ obviously happens **iff** the first $5$ coin tosses are alternating results. This means we have two possibilities and hence $P(A_1^c)=\frac{2}{32}=\frac{1}{16}\implies P(A_1)=\frac{15}{16}$.*"

---

At first sight this sample solution seemed so simple and intuitive that I didn't question it. However, after thinking about it for a while I was wondering how to derive this result rigorously.

How do I define a sample space $\Omega$ and a $\sigma$-algebra to come up with the probability in the sample solution?

Comment: You can have $\Omega=2^{\mathbb N}$ as the outcome of an infinite sequence of coin tosses, and a sigma-algebra which contains the events "the $n$th toss is Heads" for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: @Henry, is there another way to derive the probabilites rigorously? I am just a bit confused that this problem requires an uncountable sample space because it was one of the first examples we had discussed in our lecture. So I expected a much simpler approach to solve it.

Comment: You can invent a smaller sample space which only has the events you care about: elements where the tosses start with heads then alternate until the $k$th and then the $k+1$th is the same as the $k$th; elements where the tosses start with tails then alternate until the $k$th and then the $k+1$th is the same as the $k$th; an element starting with heads which alternate forever; and an element starting with tails which alternate forever.  That would be a countable sample space, with a sigma-algebra being its power set.

Comment: @Henry, in the case of your proposed countable $\Omega$, how would you argue that the probability of the two elements that alternate forever must be zero? I mean cannot simply plug them into the given probability function and check the limit as it only is defined for finite tuples.

Comment: You can add up the probabilities of all the terminating sequences and show that this is $1$.  That leaves $1-1=0$ to be divided into two non-negative probabilities for the two elements of  infinitely alternating sequences.

Comment: @Henry, I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly. So basically you are saying that all finite elements of the sample space consume all the probability so that nothing is left for the two infinite elements, right?

Comment: $\Omega$ from Henry's comment:
$$
\begin{array} {l|c}
\hline 
\omega & \mathsf{P}(\omega) \\
\hline 00 & 2^{-2} \\
\hline 11 & 2^{-2} \\
\hline 011 & 2^{-3} \\
\hline 100 & 2^{-3} \\ 
\hline 0100 & 2^{-4} \\ 
\hline 1011 & 2^{-4} \\ 
\hline 01011 & 2^{-5} \\
\hline 10100 & 2^{-5} \\ 
\hline \cdots & \cdots 
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Just add that up and you get $1$.  You do not even need a fair coin, just a memoryless one